# 'Add to home screen' website cannot access camera (iOS 11)

Tags: safari, photos, camera, ios

We're facing the issue that websites that have been added to the home screen can't access the camera anymore with iOS 11. That is, after clicking the input (type file) 'Choose file' button the options 'Take Photo or Video', 'Photo Library' and 'Browse' are shown as normal. Choosing the first one opens the camera but the screen stays black, no matter what.

I've tried with the latest update (11.0.2) but the behaviour is the same.

I tried to debug the website but it simply doesn't show up in Safari > Develop menu (it shows up if opened normally with Safari, not when added to home screen).

The upload works as expected if the site is opened normally in Safari, ie. if it's not added to the home screen.

Any ideas appreciated!

**EDIT**

It seems to be a known issue if `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` is set.

More at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228218/how-to-access-camera-on-ios11-home-screen-web-app

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85665

Comment: Can you please include the URL of the site you want to use? I have tried http://iempty.tooliphone.net/en/add-invisible-blank-icon-on-springboard-home-screen-iphone-ipad-ios/ and the camera responds just fine. Can you try this site as well and report back?

Comment: @oa- Thx, that works for me too. The site in question is only internally available, sry. I'm not the original developer but helping to fix the issue. What I've seen is that `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` and `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` is used. Maybe that causes the problem?

Comment: Just found https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85665. Seems related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limitation was fixed in iOS 11.3.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185448

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228218/how-to-access-camera-on-ios11-home-screen-web-app